# Having all Views in the Shared folder - works but is throwing "caught exceptions". Performance concern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, performance, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a simple but heavily used app done in VS2010/MVC2.  I didn't like having separate folders for each view/controller and so have all the views in the Shared folder.  It's working fine but while debugging in VS, I noticed that it's throwing IO "caught exceptions" since it seems to be looking in the [FolderName]/[ViewName] folder before going down to the Shared folder.

Again, the app runs fine but I'm concerned that all these "caught exceptions" will have a minor performance impact since they do have a cost in via the CLR.  Is there any way I can configure the Routing so that it will only look in the Shared folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Debug mode yes, in Release mode view locations are cached, so don't worry about performance unless you are shipping your site in Debug mode. Check out [this post](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/22/how-to-improve-htmlhelper.renderpartial-performances-donrsquot-run-in-debug-mode.aspx).